# Заморозка интерфейса Qt при использовании API PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qthread

Прошу помощи в диагностике проблемы:

Есть проект Qt 5.14.2 который развивается в мультиплатформенном варианте. Работает с базой данных PostgreSQL (от 9.x до 15.x). Непосредственная разработка ведётся в Win 10 x64 с компилятором MSVC 2022 x64 и тестируется по Linux x64. В рамках проекта не используется встроенный плагин Qt pgsql (причины есть - но они не столь важны). Вместо него пишется набор своих интерфейсных классов, которые взаимодействуют с Postgre через libpq, что позволяет осуществлять полный контроль над БД через API.

**Возникла задача:** грузить результаты одной view в фоновом режиме. Количество записей в запросе достигает ~50 тыс. и всё время растёт, хотя и не очень быстро. Был реализован дополнительный поток QThread, который загружает необходимое параллельно работе программы.

**Проблема:** возникает 2 заморозки:

- первая, когда в потоке запрашиваются данные, она объяснима и по сути не влияет ни на что;
- вторая - в конце процесса загрузки и вот она замораживает интерфейс программы насмерть.

Проблема во второй заморозке, вернее в том, что она замораживает интерфейс всей программы, хотя чисто технически вполне себе объяснима.

Итак детали:

1. Как уже сказал есть собственные объекты взаимодействия с PostgreSQL, которые работаю так как мне нужно. Если будет важен код - приведу позже.
2. Создается QThread с объектом, обеспечивающим загрузку:

```
     void Model::LoadData()
        {
            //-- запускаем поток, загрузки данных
            load_thread = new QThread(); //-- переменная определена в классе
            load_thread->setObjectName("BW_load");
            mtLoader = new ubiVulLoader(&DataList);
            mtLoader->moveToThread(load_thread);
            connect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(setProgressMax(int)), this, SLOT(setProgressMax(int)));
            connect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(setProgress(int)), this, SLOT(setProgress(int)), Qt::DirectConnection);
            connect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(endProcess()), this, SLOT(endProcess()));
            connect(load_thread, SIGNAL(started()), mtLoader, SLOT(doLoad()));
            load_thread->start();
        }
```

при окончании (после emit endProcess) отрабатывается следующий код:

```
void Model::endProcess()
{
    emit sendProcessEnd();
    disconnect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(setProgressMax(int)), this, SLOT(setProgressMax(int)));
    disconnect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(setProgress(int)), this, SLOT(setProgress(int)));
    disconnect(mtLoader, SIGNAL(endProcess()), this, SLOT(endProcess()));
    load_thread->quit();
    load_thread->wait(); //-- или deleteLater() - без разницы
    delete mtLoader;
    delete load_thread;
}
```

сама функция doLoad() (сокращенно) выглядит так:

```
void mtLoader::doLoad()
{
    auto con = new TConnector();
    if (con->Open())
    {
        if (con->transactionStart())
        {
            //-- ВСЕ ДЕЙСТВИЯ ВЫПОЛНЯЮТСЯ В РАМКАХ ОДНОЙ (!!!) ТРАНЗАКЦИИ
            /*
            Использование функций доступа по номеру поля а не по его имени существенно ускоряет
            обработку.  */

            QString q_load =
                QString("select " ... тут много полей по порядку
                        " from table ..."); 

            TQuery *qc = con->CreateNewQuery("select count(*) from table");
            long cnt = 0;
            if (qc->Execute())
            {
                cnt = qc->FieldByNum(0).toLongLong();
            }
            delete qc;
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                emit setProgressMax(cnt); //-- оповещение о максимуме
                recs->resize(cnt); 
                //-- чтобы не перегружать событиями основной интерфейс искусственно снизим частоту оповещения
                //-- см. в конец цикла
                auto step = cnt / 100;
                auto st = 0;
                int progress = 0;

                TQuery *q = con->CreateNewQuery(q_load);
                if (q->Execute())
                {
                    int cnt = q->getRowCount();
                    TData *rec = nullptr;
                    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
                    {
                        recs->data()[i] = new TData();
                        rec = recs->at(i);
                        //-- служебные поля таблицы
                        rec->id = q->FieldByNum(0).toLongLong(); 
                        rec->code = q->FieldByNum(2).toString();
                        rec->name = q->FieldByNum(1).toString();
                        
                        ... ну и так далее заполняем объект

                        //--
                        q->Next();

                        //-- чтобы не перегружать событиями основной интерфейс искусственно снизим частоту оповещения
                        //-- оповещение о прогрессе будем отсылать 1 раз за 1 процент выполнения, а не на каждую запись
                        st += 1;
                        progress+=1;
                        if (st > step)
                        {
                            st = 0;
                            emit setProgress(progress);  //-- оповещение о прогрессе выполнения
                        }
                    }
                    emit setProgress(progress);  //-- оповещение о прогрессе выполнения
                }
                else
                {
                    //-- в случае ошибки ...
                    con->transactionRollback();
                    con->Close();
                    delete q;
                    delete con;
                    return;
                }
                delete q; //-- <<<< FREEZE
            }
        }
        con->transactionRollback();
        con->Close();
    }
    delete con;
    emit endProcess(); //-- оповещение об окончании процесса
}
```

собственно вторая заморозка возникает при удалении объекта q, в процессе которой выполняется код:

```
...
    if (_res!=nullptr)
    {
        PQclear(_res); //-- <<<< FREEZE
        _res=nullptr;
    }
    ...
```

точки заморозки указаны "FREEZE". В последнем коде вызов функции обязателен перед завершением запроса для устранения утечки памяти - это требование API PostgreSQL.

Умом я понимаю, что очистка блока памяти моего размера, в принципе не быстрое дело, но: всё выполняется в отдельном потоке а замораживается интерфейс всей программы.

Первая мысль: сделать (и сделано) объект типа DataReader с чтением по строкам, но он работает в разы медленнее, поскольку такая функция очистки вызывается для каждой полученной записи с сервера (при использовании построчного режима).

Вторая мысль: Объекты TConnector / TQuery - простые классы, не наследники от QObject. Пока не проверял.

В любом случае, возникает вопрос: при работе с сервером в ОТДЕЛЬНОМ ПОТОКЕ вызов его API функции вызывает фриз интерфейса всей программы. Почему?

**UPD 1**: В C# есть NpgSQL, работающий с PostgreSQL напрямую. У него есть DataReader, с которым не возникает таких сложностей в другом проекте, подключённом к этой же БД. Повторить тут не смог.

Прошу поделиться мыслями.

Comment: А как реализован механизм синхронизации данных модели с данными, которые загружены из БД?

Comment: Обновление реализовано через асинхронные сообщения PostgreSQL. Есть класс, который отслеживает (через API Postgre) и рассылает моделям для обработки. там все просто как табуретка. Единственное - в каждой таблице реализован триггер на события, который рассылает сообщения в JSON-формате. Если нужны подробности, могу поделиться в личных сообщениях кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Описанная проблема исчезает, стоит только собрать проект не под отладкой а Release сборку. Решил отписаться, мало ли кто столкнется с похожим... :)

Comment: так в vs2022 хороший profiler встроенный, наверное можно определить куда в Debug время уходит

Comment: Всё бы ничего, но я использую компилятор MSVC 2022 в комплекте с QtCreator. Да, можно и профилировщиком, но не хочу терять время, может позже. Программа созданная для релиза и запускаемая без отладки и самостоятельно а не в среде разработки фризов не имеет.

Comment: так ничего не мешает и тем и тем пользоваться, vs-проект делается из pro `qmake.exe -t vcapp file.pro`, я так обычно и делаю, классы, файлы и слоты создаю в qtcreator, а компиляция и отладка в vs